# How is that .value can be called on a SettingKey or TaskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

One can write something like

```
(managedClasspath in Compile).value
```

to obtain the value of `managedClasspath` in the `Compile` configuration.

The type of `(managedClasspath in Compile)` is yet again a [sbt.TaskKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.TaskKey) (because we call the `in` method with a `ConfigKey`).

There is however no `value` method on `SettingKey` or `TaskKey`, and I can't find any implicit class that provides such a method. So how come it exists? Is this some magical macro voodoo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's both, there are a few things at work components:

1. In sbt, any `*XYZKey[_]` can be converted into an appropriate `Initialize[_]` instance via an implicit.   This, by default, is an initializer that reads the existing value at the key and returns it.
2. The `sbt.std.MacroValue[T]` type is a compile-time only class which holds something that can have .value called on it:  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.std.MacroValue.  We use this to track the underlying instances in the macro and denote that they have special significance (i.e. we have to rework the code such that we wait for the value to exist before using it).
3. The `sbt.Def` object has a set of implicits called `macroValueXYZ` which lift `Initialize[_]` instances into the macro API.

So, as you can see, it's a bit of black magic through our internals to get there.   We'll have to look into a way to better document the API in a scaladoc tool.

Comment: In item 1, `*XYZKey[_]` are converted into `Initialize[_]` without the aid of `implicit`. `*XYZKey[_]` inherit from `Initialize[_]`.